# how can I catch a single variable in array of Object in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter

I have probabbly a eal probleme with array . I have a request :
in my model

```
 public function getHomme ($limit ,$offset)
 {
     $this->db->select('id,nom,prix,nom_marques,nom_path,quantite,semelle_interieure,libelle_fermeture,libelle_style,libelle_talon,libelle_doublure,libelle_semelle,libelle_dessus');
     $this->db->from('chaussure');
     $this->db->join('gnr_convenir', 'gnr_convenir.identifiant_chaussure = chaussure.id');
     $this->db->join('images', 'images.id_chaussure = chaussure.id');
     $this->db->join('marques', 'marques.idmarques = chaussure.identifiant_marques');
     $this->db->join('fermeture', 'fermeture.idfermeture = chaussure.identifiant_fermeture');
     $this->db->join('style', 'style.idstyle = chaussure.identifiant_style');
     $this->db->join('talon', 'talon.idtalon = chaussure.identifiant_talon');
     $this->db->join('doublure', 'doublure.iddoublure = chaussure.identifiant_doublure');
     $this->db->join('materiauSemelle', 'materiauSemelle.idmateriauSemelle = chaussure.identifiant_semelle');
     $this->db->join('dessus', 'dessus.iddessus = chaussure.identifiant_dessus');
     $this->db->where('identifiant_genre', 1);  
     $this->db->order_by("id", "desc");
     $this->db->limit($limit,$offset);

     $query = $this->db->get();

     $ligne= $query->num_rows();

     if($query->num_rows()>0)
     {
         foreach($query->result()as $row)
         {
             $data[] = $row; 
         }

         $data['ligne'] = $ligne;

         return $data;
     }
```

so here I need 2 things:
one the object on data and the other is `$ligne` (number of rows )

so it seems like this when I try to make `var_dump($data)`

```
array
'rows' => 
array
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[21]
      public 'id' => string '89' (length=2)
      public 'nom' => string 'zoro' (length=4)
      public 'prix' => string '12460.00' (length=8)

  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[22]
      public 'id' => string '87' (length=2)
      public 'nom' => string 'adizero' (length=7)
      public 'prix' => string '124000.00' (length=9)

  'ligne' => int 2
```

but when I try to write:

`var_dump($data['ligne'])` in my controller

I have an error message

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined index: ligne
>
> Filename: controllers/client.php
>
> Line Number: 143
>
> null

I need those 2 data in my view, so in my view I thought to use `$ligne` like this:

```
$numberLigne = $ligne ;
```

Comment: Please attempt to properly format your code so it's readable by others.

Answer (score 0):

As a test, could you echo ligne in your model to make sure that your join query is working right? I have no way of knowing without seeing your full table.

Also, any reason why you use:

```
if($query->num_rows()>0)
```

Instead of

```
 if($ligne > 0):
```

Being that you just set that variable?